# popup panel how to hide link title?

Tags: javascript, html

I hope you can help. I am using a popup panel which show up when you press the black **ffff** button

but when the popup panel opens up you get the text **ffff** with a blue shadow around it in the top left hand corner. It disapears when you click on it

Is there away of getting rid of it please as I cant seem to do it???

its linked to

```
<a class="lnk_modal-open" 
href="http://www.stamfordstriders.org" 
data-modal>
ffff
</a>
```

and then the js file

So at the moment the. **fff** text shows on both the black button and the popup panel

Hope you can helps thanks Tim

[image: popup panel with text issue]

```js
// https://john-dugan.com/javascript-debounce/
var debounce = function(e, t, n) {
  var a;
  return function() {
    var r = this,
      i = arguments,
      o = function() {
        a = null, n || e.apply(r, i)
      },
      s = n && !a;
    clearTimeout(a), a = setTimeout(o, t || 200), s && e.apply(r, i)
  }
};


(function(window, d, debounce) {

  "use strict";

  // Modal pop-up window iframe version 4.1 22-08-2016

  // v4.1 - Launch from an anchor link, button or any other not recommended object
  // modal title text set by data-modalTitle, image alt or link text.
  // Object with .-modal (modalName) with have .-modal-open appended === "-" + modalName + contentClass

  // To do - under consideration:
  // make lightbox the modal section and code around it?
  // perhaps <section class=modal = lightbox
  //            <div =modal_inner = modal?
  // lightbox doesnt need to be in keychain just add onclick to close

  // To do:
  //    Option to set an ideal pop-up size eg an image
  //      - maintain the aspect ratio
  //      - centre it

  // Requires:
  //    SVG definitions for: #icon-cross, #icon-loading
  //    External functions: debounce()

  // Assumptions:
  //    First object in modal is the modal title
  //    Last object is the modal close link


  // defaults
  var modalName = "modal";
  var lightboxClass = "lightbox";
  var openClass = "-" + modalName + "-open";
  //var modalDesc = "<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift + tab</kbd> to move focus.";
  var modalDesc = "Tab or Shift + Tab to move focus.";


  var _setContentObjs = function(isModalOpen) {
    var objs = d.getElementsByClassName("-" + modalName);
    var i = objs.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (!!isModalOpen) {
        objs[i].classList.add(openClass);
        if (objs[i].tagName.toLowerCase !== "body") {
          objs[i].setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        }
      } else {
        objs[i].classList.remove(openClass);
        objs[i].removeAttribute("aria-hidden");
      }
    }
    return !!isModalOpen;
  };


  var _closeModal = function(e) {
    var count = e.target.count; // = lightbox, modal (ESC key), close btn
    var modalSection = d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + count);
    var lightbox = d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + count + "_" + lightboxClass);
    var modalLink;
    if (modalSection) {
      modalSection.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
      lightbox.className = lightbox.className.replace(lightboxClass + "-on", "");

      _setContentObjs(!modalSection.getAttribute("aria-hidden"));
      modalLink = d.getElementById(modalSection.returnId);
      d.body.classList.remove(openClass);
      modalLink.focus();
    }
  };


  var _getModalSize = function(modalSection) {
    var clone = modalSection.cloneNode(true);
    var size = {};
    clone.className = modalName;
    clone.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;visibility:hidden;transform: none");
    modalSection.parentElement.appendChild(clone);
    size.width = clone.clientWidth; // more performant than getBoundingClientRect
    size.height = clone.clientHeight; // more performant than getBoundingClientRect
    modalSection.parentElement.removeChild(clone);
    return size;
  };


  var _resizeIframes = function() {

    var size;
    var iframes;
    var ii;

    var modals = d.getElementsByClassName(modalName);
    var i = modals.length;

    while (i--) {

      size = _getModalSize(modals[i]);

      iframes = modals[i].getElementsByClassName(modalName + "_iframe");
      ii = iframes.length;

      while (ii--) {
        iframes[ii].width = size.width;
        iframes[ii].height = size.height;
      }
    }
  };


  var _addIframe = function(modalSection) {

    var size;
    var close_lnk;
    var frames = modalSection.getElementsByClassName(modalName + "_iframe");
    var iframe;
    if (!frames[0]) {

      iframe = d.createElement("iframe");

      // Don't display iframe until it's content is ready
      iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
        iframe.classList.add(modalName + "_iframe-on");
      }, false);

      iframe.src = modalSection.modalSrc;
      iframe.className = modalName + "_iframe";

      size = _getModalSize(modalSection);
      iframe.width = size.width;
      iframe.height = size.height;

      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
      iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", true);

      // Add iframe before the close button
      close_lnk = d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + modalSection.count + "_lnk_close");
      modalSection.insertBefore(iframe, close_lnk);

    }
  };


  var _getTarget = function(obj) {
    var target = obj;
    var isBodyTag = obj.tagName.toLowerCase() === "body";
    if (isBodyTag) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!obj.modalSrc) {
      target = _getTarget(obj.parentElement);
    }
    return target;
  }


  var _openModal = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var target = _getTarget(e.target);

    if (target) {

      var count = target.count;
      var tempId = modalName + "_" + count;
      var tempLightboxClass = modalName + "_" + lightboxClass;
      var modalSection = d.getElementById(tempId);
      var lightbox = d.getElementById(tempId + "_" + lightboxClass);

      if (modalSection && lightbox) {
        if (!lightbox.className.match(tempLightboxClass + "-on")) {
          lightbox.className += " " + tempLightboxClass + "-on";
        }
        modalSection.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        _addIframe(modalSection);

        _setContentObjs(!!modalSection.getAttribute("aria-hidden"));

        d.body.classList.add(openClass);
        d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + count + "_title").focus();
      }
    }
  };


  var _keydown_openerObj = function(e) {
    // enter or space from the opener object
    if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _openModal(e);
    }
  };


  var _addOpenModalLinkAttr = function(modalLink) {
    modalLink.id = modalLink.id || "modal_" + modalLink.count + "_lnk";
    modalLink.setAttribute("aria-controls", modalName + "_" + modalLink.count);

    // test if it's not a button
    var tag = modalLink.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag !== "button") {
      modalLink.setAttribute("aria-role", "button");
      modalLink.addEventListener("keydown", _keydown_openerObj, false);
    }

    // click only requires space and enter activtion too
    if (tag !== "a" || "button") {
      modalLink.tabIndex = 0;
    }

    modalLink.addEventListener("click", _openModal, false);
  };


  var _keydown_modal = function(e) {

    var target = e.target;

    // ESC key on anything actionable
    if (e.which === 27) {
      _closeModal(e);
    }

    // tab key and shift on the h1
    if (e.which === 9 && e.shiftKey) {
      if (target.classList.contains(modalName + "_title")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //focus on last object in modal (close btn)
        d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + e.target.count + "_lnk_close").focus();
      }
    }

    // tab key and not shift on the close link.
    if (e.which === 9 && !e.shiftKey) {
      if (target.classList.contains(modalName + "_lnk-close")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //focus on first object in modal - or should it be the modal? Requires testing
        d.getElementById(modalName + "_" + e.target.count + "_title").focus();
      }
    }

    // enter or space on the close link - why again??
    if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 32) {
      if (target.classList.contains(modalName + "_lnk-close")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _closeModal(e);
      }
    }
  };


  var _getTitleText = function(modalLink) {
    var alt = "";
    var imgs = modalLink.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if (imgs && imgs[0]) {
      alt = imgs[0].alt;
    }
    return modalLink.getAttribute("data-modalTitle") || alt || modalLink.textContent;
  };


  var _getModalTitle = function(modalLink) {
    var title = d.createElement("h1");
    title.id = modalName + "_" + modalLink.count + "_title";
    title.className = modalName + "_title";
    title.tabIndex = 0;
    title.textContent = _getTitleText(modalLink);
    title.count = modalLink.count;
    title.addEventListener("keydown", _keydown_modal, false);
    return title;
  };


  var _getModalSVG = function(icon, clss, title) {
    var svg = d.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.classList.add(clss);
    if (title) {
      var t = d.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title");
      t.textContent = title;
      svg.appendChild(t);
    }
    var use = d.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#" + icon);
    svg.appendChild(use);
    return svg;
  };


  var _getModalDesc = function(modalLink) {
    var desc = d.createElement("p");
    desc.id = modalName + "_" + modalLink.count + "_desc";
    desc.className = modalName + "_desc";
    desc.tabIndex = 0;
    desc.innerHTML = modalLink.getAttribute("data-modalDesc") || modalDesc;
    desc.count = modalLink.count;
    desc.addEventListener("keydown", _keydown_modal, false);
    return desc;
  };


  var _getModalCloseLink = function(modalLink) {
    var link = d.createElement("a");
    link.id = modalName + "_" + modalLink.count + "_lnk_close";
    link.className = modalName + "_lnk-close";
    link.tabIndex = 0;
    link.appendChild(_getModalSVG("icon-cross", "svg-close", "Close modal"));
    link.count = modalLink.count;
    link.addEventListener("click", _closeModal, false);
    link.addEventListener("keydown", _keydown_modal, false);
    return link;
  };


  var _addModalSection = function(modalLink) {
    var section = d.createElement("section");
    section.id = modalName + "_" + modalLink.count;
    section.count = modalLink.count;
    section.returnId = modalLink.id;
    section.className = modalName;
    section.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

    // should be on the activating link?
    section.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", modalName + "_" + modalLink.count + "_title");
    section.setAttribute("aria-describedby", modalName + "_" + modalLink.count + "_desc");

    section.setAttribute("role", "dialog");
    section.modalSrc = modalLink.modalSrc;

    section.appendChild(_getModalTitle(modalLink));
    section.appendChild(_getModalSVG("icon-loading", "svg-loading", "Loading"));
    section.appendChild(_getModalSVG("icon-loading", "svg-loading2", ""));
    section.appendChild(_getModalDesc(modalLink));
    section.appendChild(_getModalCloseLink(modalLink));

    d.body.appendChild(section);
  };


  var _addLightbox = function(modalLink) {

    var count = modalLink.count;
    var lightboxDiv = d.createElement("div");

    lightboxDiv.id = modalName + "_" + count + "_" + lightboxClass;
    lightboxDiv.className = modalName + "_" + lightboxClass;
    lightboxDiv.count = count;
    lightboxDiv.returnId = modalLink.id;

    // mouse / touch only
    lightboxDiv.addEventListener("click", _closeModal, false);

    d.body.appendChild(lightboxDiv);
  };


  var configuration = function(cfg) {
    modalName = cfg.modalName || modalName;

    lightboxClass = cfg.lightboxClass || lightboxClass;

    // any object with a class -modal will have the class -modal-open added when the modal is open.
    //openClass = "-" + modalName + (cfg.openClass || "-open");
    openClass = cfg.openClass ? "-" + modalName + cfg.openClass : openClass;
  };


  var initialise = function(cfg) {

    configuration(cfg);

    var modalSrc;
    var dataModals = d.querySelectorAll("[data-" + modalName + "]");

    if (dataModals) {
      var i = dataModals.length;
      while (i--) {

        // Link href and iframe src are not always the same!
        modalSrc = false;

        // use the href
        if (dataModals[i].hasAttribute("href")) {
          modalSrc = dataModals[i].href;
        }

        // overwrite src with data-modal content when available
        if (dataModals[i].getAttribute("data-modal").length) {
          modalSrc = dataModals[i].getAttribute("data-modal");
        }

        if (modalSrc) {
          dataModals[i].modalSrc = modalSrc;
          dataModals[i].count = i;
          _addOpenModalLinkAttr(dataModals[i]);
          _addModalSection(dataModals[i]);
          _addLightbox(dataModals[i]);
        }

      }

      window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(_resizeIframes, 250, false));

    }

  };

  initialise({
    modalName: "modal", // class name of modal, also used as the base for all classes used except on SVGs.
    openClass: "-open", // is default ("-" + modaName automatically prepended)
    lightboxClass: "lightbox" // is default (modaName + "_" automatically prepended)
  });

}(window, document, debounce));
```

```css
button,
[aria-role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[data-modal][aria-controls],
[aria-role="button"][data-modal][aria-controls] {
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}


/* Hover & focus indication. */


/* Reads as: if button, or aria-role=button, has data-model attribute and JavaScript has added aria-controls then on hover or focus */

button[data-modal][aria-controls]:hover,
button[data-modal][aria-controls]:focus,
[aria-role="button"][data-modal][aria-controls]:hover,
[aria-role="button"][data-modal][aria-controls]:focus {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(120%);
  filter: contrast(120%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, .6);
  /* Red so you can tell */
  outline: 0 solid;
}


/* Modal opening link cosmetics */

.lnk_modal-open {
  font-size: larger;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0 solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lnk_modal-img {
  padding: 0;
}

.lnk_modal-open:active {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(85%);
  filter: brightness(85%);
}

.img_modal-open {
  display: block;
  border: 0 solid;
}


/* The modal section is added via JS */

.modal {
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  background-color: #F7F0E8;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  top: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em #000;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out, visibility 0s ease-out 1s, transform .5s ease-out .5s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal[aria-hidden="false"] {
  position: fixed;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* Light box properties */

.modal_lightbox {
  text-indent: -200em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* places the modal overlay between the main page (0) and the modal dialog (10) */
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out, visibility 0s ease-out .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal_lightbox-on {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal_lightbox-on:hover {
  /* Stolen from trickle.js. Under consideration. SVGs will not work here */
  cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAANpJREFUOBGNkz0KAjEQhYPYWXgCKws7LcXWyt7WG4i9jegBvIJ4AvEyXsRCsBDiN0sGkiE/O/A2O9n3viS7rPPeb9ETrVzPwrtHDzR1XF5I6oPWLQaeq5hDXQRw0I6xCuF5HH7Tz7oFuTkhrSyEhza8THaLoQhphpWUg/QOFyA/AFpy5nTbGrIjxvg4AiiGBzYc+rGZH9KPzFy+ZbX4bX9l+VDZr5NQMMbhbtvMxccpQ3JhpTchtXATQviItIpvW0CY7HHm8c9UDRd2chbABt3RQk2tEe8O3dDkD4JQ4iOR7BMpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"), pointer;
}


/* Modal title and description */

.modal_title,
.modal_desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -200em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.125em .25em;
  /* Tesco requirement
  font-family: Tesco_W_Rg, sans-serif; */
  margin: 0;
}

.modal_title:focus,
.modal_desc:focus {
  left: 5px;
}

[aria-hidden="false"] .modal_title {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out 3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal_title,
.modal_title:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}


/* The iframe */

.modal_iframe {
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out, visibility 0s ease-out 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal_iframe-on {
  transition: opacity .8s ease-out, visibility 0s ease-out 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

[aria-hidden="true"] .modal_iframe {
  display: none;
}

[aria-hidden="false"] .modal_iframe {
  display: block;
}


/* The modal pop-ups close button, appears last in the modal, but is moved visually to the top right of the pop-up */

.modal_lnk-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  border: 0 solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
}

.modal_lnk-close:hover,
.modal_lnk-close:active,
.modal_lnk-close:focus {
  background-color: #c00;
  outline: 0 solid;
}

.svg-close {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
}


/* Modal SVG (Tesco) loading animation version 2 (overlaid on itself and out of phase) */

[class*="svg-loading"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: calc(50% - 40px);
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.svg-loading {
  fill: #00539f;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

.svg-loading2 {
  /* Match to .modal background colour for full effect */
  fill: #F7F0E8;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: rotate 5s linear 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* While modal is open */


/* Class added to body tag to prevent scroll
   Note the body does not require class "-modal" */

body.-modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Any tags classed with "-modal", when open, get "-modal-open" added */


/* Both of these are equivalent, best practice to use the attribute version which enforces accessibility */

.-modal[aria-hidden="true"] {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.-modal.-modal-open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}


/* Generic helper style */

.u-margin2 {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href=''>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylepopup.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class=-modal>


    <p>
      <a class="lnk_modal-open" href="http://www.stamfordstriders.org" data-modal>
     ffff
    </a>
    </p>


  </div>

  <svg style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 38 38" id="icon-cross">
      <path d="M19 17.6l5.3-5.4 1.4 1.4-5.3 5.4 5.3 5.3-1.4 1.4-5.3-5.3-5.3 5.3-1.4-1.4 5.2-5.3-5.2-5.3 1.4-1.4 5.3 5.3z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox='0 0 150 130' id="icon-loading">
      <title>Loading</title>
      <path d='M81.5 33l30.8-32.8c0.3-0.3 0.5-0.2 0.3 0.3 -1.8 5.2-1.7 15.3-1.7 15.3 -0.1 6.8-0.8 11.7-6.6 17.9L74.8 65.1c-0.2 0.2-0.4 0-0.3-0.2 1.5-5.1 1.2-15.1 1.2-15.1C75.4 45.6 76.4 38.4 81.5 33M105.9 54.8l43.8 10.3c0.4 0.1 0.4 0.4-0.2 0.4 -5.4 1-14.1 6.1-14.1 6.1 -6 3.3-10.5 5.2-18.8 3.2l-41.9-9.9c-0.3-0.1-0.2-0.3 0-0.4 5.2-1.3 13.7-6.5 13.7-6.5C92 55.9 98.7 53.1 105.9 54.8M99.4 86.3l13 43.2c0.1 0.4-0.1 0.5-0.4 0.1 -3.6-4.2-12.4-9.2-12.4-9.2 -5.8-3.5-9.7-6.5-12.2-14.6L75 64.5c-0.1-0.3 0.2-0.4 0.3-0.2 3.7 3.9 12.5 8.6 12.5 8.6C91.5 74.8 97.3 79.2 99.4 86.3M68.7 97l-30.8 32.8c-0.3 0.3-0.5 0.2-0.3-0.3 1.8-5.2 1.7-15.3 1.7-15.3 0.1-6.8 0.8-11.7 6.6-17.9l29.5-31.4c0.2-0.2 0.4 0 0.3 0.2 -1.5 5.1-1.2 15.1-1.2 15.1C74.8 84.4 73.8 91.6 68.7 97M44.1 75.8L0.3 65.4C-0.1 65.3-0.1 65 0.5 65c5.4-1 14.1-6.1 14.1-6.1 6-3.3 10.5-5.2 18.8-3.2l41.9 9.9c0.3 0.1 0.2 0.3 0 0.4 -5.2 1.3-13.7 6.5-13.7 6.5C58.1 74.7 51.3 77.5 44.1 75.8M50.2 43.8l-13-43.2c-0.1-0.4 0.1-0.5 0.4-0.1C41.2 4.7 50 9.7 50 9.7c5.8 3.5 9.7 6.5 12.2 14.6l12.4 41.3c0.1 0.3-0.2 0.4-0.3 0.2 -3.7-3.9-12.5-8.6-12.5-8.6C58.1 55.4 52.4 50.9 50.2 43.8'/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
  <!-- partial -->



  <script src="scriptpopup.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ffff` text is rendered in an element with the `.modal_title` class. Look up that class in the CSS file and add the following rule after the other rules for this class.

```
.modal_title {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - Ive also found the code within the js for display which I can delete. I was searching for ages and always seemed to miss it.